# Questions about hyperparameter tuning in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am studying deep learning recently, mainly rely on Andrew Ng's Deep Learning Specialization on Coursera.

And I want to build my own model to classify `MNIST` with 99% accuracy (simple MLP model, not CNN). So I use `KerasClassifier` to wrap my model and use `GridsearchCV` to fine tune the hyperparameters (including hidden layer number, units number, dropout rate, etc.)

However, when I google "fine tuning", the majority of the results are mainly on "transfer learning", which are just tuning the learning rate, output layer number or freeze layer number.

I know these famous models are capable to deal with many problems with just a little changes. But what if I want to build a tiny model from scratch to handle a special question, what are the common/best practice?

So my questions are mainly about the common/best practice of fine tuning model:

1. What is the common/best way to fine tuning? (I have seen people tune hyperparameters manually, or using scikit-learn's `RandomizedSearchCV`/`GridSearchCV`, or `hyperas`)
2. Should I use k-fold cross validation? (Because it's the default set of `GridSearchCV`, and it extremely increases the training time but helps little)
3. Is it enough to solve most problems by slightly modifying the off-the-shelf models? If not, to what direction should I move on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In deep learning, fine tuning usually refers to retraining certain layers of a pretrained model on data from a new domain. I believe you are looking for something like "hyperparameter optimisation". There are various ways to approach this. People have their own preferences regarding the best method. Using RandomizedSearchCV/GridSearch CV or a combination of the two is fine. Trial and error using a few configurations is fine. People sometimes retrain well known architectures completely. Others resort to more complicated approaches, such as opmtimising hyperparameters using evolutionary programming (genetic algorithms). So you're kinda spoiled for choice.
2. Cross validation is usually only required if your data set is small, and further splitting into a train and  test set reduces the size of the test set, decreasing statistical significance (reliability) of your results. If you have enough data, you can go ahead and just split into train/val/test sets. But its usually necessary since since large amounts of labelled data tend to be rare.
3. If off-the-shelf models are available for the problem you are trying to solve, use them! While familiarising yourself with the implementation and source code is insightful, there's no need to reinvent the wheel and rewrite these solutions!